# How to traverse every element of the document using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, element, traversal

as above.  How to **traverse** every element of the document using javascript?

Comment: [You could use a tree walker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker)

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*")).forEach((el) => { ... })`

Comment: Does the answer solve the problem? If so, could you mark this as correct by clicking the check mark to the left. That way, it will no longer turn up in the list of unsolved questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could select all elements by passing * to `getElementsByTagName()` like this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
    console.log(all[i].nodeName);
}
```